# UITableviewCell show extra label in when device in landscape

Tags: ios10, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- In a UITableViewCell I have an StackView with 3 labels, but I wanna show only two of them in portrait and all of them when in landscape mode.

What I've tried to do was: add a customization for the *installed* property that's only checked when the device is in CxC... But when I run the app and rotate the emulator I get this on the debug: *pending: position from NSPoint: {36.5, 15} to Optional(NSPoint: {40.5, 15})*

I've attached an image show what I want to achieve.

Thanks a lot[image: ![tableview]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO9tR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find orientation by getting device orientation status and hide the third label

```
 if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft{
    cell.thirdLabel.hidden = false
    }
    else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight{
    cell.thirdLabel.hidden = false

    }
    else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown{
    cell.thirdLabel.hidden = true
    }
    else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.UIDeviceOrientationPortrait{
   cell.thirdLabel.hidden = true
    }
```

You can use the two and remove others

Comment: Hi there... I've tried your code but still doesn't work... Still getting _ pending: position from NSPoint: {36.5, 15} to Optional(NSPoint: {40.5, 15})_ when rotate device...

Comment: If you are using any libraries update them to latest version also if you are using animations check if they are compatible in both modes else update.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Not using animations, all libraries updated (Realm)